# Source generated commentary

Tags: dtx, source, docstrip

Had a look at `source2e.pdf` and `source3.pdf`.  From what I understand, the developers of latex include commentary in the source files.  The source files can then be processed by some tool to make a source-generated commentary file.  These being `source2e.pdf` and `source3.pdf`.

Can I have more details about this, further reading on the process ?

Comment: just run pdflatex on source2e.tex

Comment: as I said before `texdoc doc` will document the documentation style used, there is no separate tool or extraction process, the dtx files are tex files.

Comment: `source2e.tex` gets produced after processing ?

Comment: no, as you could see if you looked at the distribution, source2e.tex is a small file that sets up the latex typesetting then inputs each of the dtx source files. http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.tex

Comment: Is the `doc` package similar to `doxygen` (that generates documentation from annotated C++ sources) ?

Comment: not really, it's inverted. doxygen is an application that runs on the source, doc is just a latex package, like any other package, the latex sources are primarily a latex document. The tex sources are extracted (by a different tex file, docstrip) from the document, not as in doxygen extracting document from source. (tex.web is similar)

Comment: You end up with a collection of files with the commentary only.  Then you have a master latex file bringing them all together in a single document.

Comment: No, running pdflatex on source2e makes a single pdf file of all the 2e sources

Comment: Was referring to `source2e` as the master file (calling all `.dtx` files of all 2e sources).  With each `.dtx` file being the original code with only the source documentation part (the implementation code have been stripped out).

Comment: Latex packages are written as a dtx file containing source code and documentation (written in commented style) in the same file. What is the purpose of extracting the class files only from it, or the embedded documentation. Cannot one just have the two together ?

Comment: you could read texdoc docstrip instead of flooding this site with so many basic questions. the doc is not extracted, the code is as it is generated, not literally on the source document as literal code

Comment: "with each .dtx file being the original code with only the source documentation part" ????  I can not guess what you mean by that. The dtx files are the documentation and source.

Comment: They contain both.

Comment: Yes the runtime files may be extracted from the source document (dtx) but I can't guess what you mean by "only the source documentation part" but no matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst not a requirement, a common approach for LaTeX sources is to place the code and commentary into `.dtx` files, referred to as 'DocTeX' by some editors. (The LaTeX team do not use this term: they are simply `.dtx` files.)
These source files contain the code for one or more class, package or support files *and* the supporting comments/documentation. The `.dtx` file can then be processed in one of two ways.

First, there should be an accompanying `.ins` file. The latter is a set of instructions on how to extract the class/package from the `.dtx`. We normally extract using plain TeX, so something like

```
pdftex mypkg.ins
```

in the common case would extract whatever is in `mypkg.dtx`. (It is possible to combine the `.ins` and `.dtx` into one source, but this is not the recommended pattern.) This extraction process uses a tool written in TeX called DocStrip.

The other way to use the `.dtx` is to treat it like any other LaTeX source

```latex
pdflatex mypkg.dtx
```

LaTeX doesn't care what extension is used, so this is typeset normally. The way a `.dtx` is structured is such that used in this way, the documentation/comments will be typeset along with the code.

---

For smaller packages using the `.dtx` mechanism, it is likely that one `.dtx`/`.ins` combination contains the source for exactly one `.sty` or `.cls` file. However, that is not a necessity. It is possible to pack several package files into one `.dtx`, or to extract multiple `.dtx` files in one go to give a single output package, etc.

The LaTeX kernel is very large, and therefore has both many `.dtx` files and many target files to be generated. It also needs to typeset multiple versions from the same sources. For this reason, it has a complex `.ins`/`.dtx` structure *and* additional `.tex` files that input some `.dtx` files to allow finer control. As such, it's not where I'd start in understanding the `.dtx` model.

---

As indicated above, the extraction part of the process uses a tool called DocStrip, for which one can `texdoc docstrip`. The sources for `.dtx` files make use of a LaTeX package called `doc`, which provides the necessary mark-up tools for source documentation.

The tools provided include for example the ability to typeset only the documentation part of a source, and to skip the implementation part. That means that many `.dtx` files are rarely typeset in full: the source part is there but only ever read by the developer. It is possible to pass an option to `doc` to adjust this, and there are therefore several ways to set up typesetting to provide two PDFs, one with the documentation only and one with the implementation.

---

For a single package or class file, extracting the sources is nowadays less important. (Historically, there was a need to avoid forcing TeX to read lots of comment lines when this was not needed, but increasing computer performance has negated this.) However, once you want to split your source into multiple files or to extract more than one file from a single source, it becomes very useful. See https://github.com/latex3/latex3/tree/main/l3backend for an example of multiple sources extracting multiple files which isn't as complex as the 2e kernel.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148914/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-source-generated-commentary); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.